# Having trouble with diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, breadcrumbs

Hi please help me i am facing with eror.I did all as documentation.I use diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs package

```
// routes/breadcrumbs.php file like this:

Breadcrumbs::for('pages', function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail,  App\Models\Pages $page) {

    if(is_null($page->parent_id))
    {

        $trail->parent('home');
    }
    else
    {
        $trail->parent('pages', $page->parent_id);
    }

    switch (LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale())
    {
        case "uz":  $trail->push($page->title_uz,route('page.show',['data'=> $page->slug]));
            break;
        case "ru":  $trail->push($page->title_ru,route('page.show',['data'=> $page->slug]));
            break;
        case "en":  $trail->push($page->title_en,route('page.show',['data'=> $page->slug]));
            break;
    }

});
```

In view file i call it like this:

`{{ Breadcrumbs::render('pages', $page) }}`

In result i get this error

`Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider::{closure}(): Argument dwightwatson/breadcrumbs#2 ($page) must be of type App\Models\Pages, int given, called in C:\OSPanel\domains\laravel.loc\vendor\diglactic\laravel-breadcrumbs\src\Generator.php on line 64`

Comment: Exactly what it says, the value in $page is not an instance of App\Models\Pages, but an integer. I suspect that wherever you pass the $page you are not passing an instance of the model but it's ID.